# Asynchronous testing in rxjava not working

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, rx-java

I am trying to unit test my use case the following way:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DeviceCheckInUseCaseTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    ShopRepository shopRepository;

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    SettingRepository settingRepository;

    private DeviceCheckInUseCase deviceCheckInUseCase;

    private PublishSubject<CheckInResult> checkinSubject;

    private static final String SHOPID = "shop id";
    private static final String MEMBERID = "member id";

    private TestSubscriber<CheckInResult> testSubscriber;

    @Mock
    Activity activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
        checkinSubject = PublishSubject.create();

        when(shopRepository
            .checkIn(
                activity,
                SHOPID,
                MEMBERID,
                -60
            )
        ).thenReturn(checkinSubject.asObservable());

        when(settingRepository.getCheckinRssiThreshold()).thenReturn(-60);

        deviceCheckInUseCase = new DeviceCheckInUseCase(userRepository, shopRepository, settingRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCheckInSucceeded() {
        final ArrayList<CheckInResult> succeeded = new ArrayList<CheckInResult>();
        final ArrayList<Throwable> failed = new ArrayList<Throwable>();

        this.deviceCheckInUseCase.checkIn(activity, SHOPID, MEMBERID)
            .doOnNext(new Action1<CheckInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void call(CheckInResult checkInResult) {
                    succeeded.add(checkInResult);
                }
            })
            .doOnError(new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    failed.add(throwable);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(testSubscriber)
        ;

        testSubscriber.assertValueCount(0);
        assertEquals(0, succeeded.size());
        assertEquals(0, failed.size());

        checkinSubject.onNext(new CheckInSuccess());

        this.testSubscriber.assertValueCount(1);
        assertEquals(1, succeeded.size());
        assertEquals(0, failed.size());
    }
}
```

And below is my `DeviceCheckInUseCase.java`

```
public class DeviceCheckInUseCase {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private ShopRepository shopRepository;
    private SettingRepository settingRepository;
//    private Subscription


    @Inject
    public DeviceCheckInUseCase(UserRepository userRepository, ShopRepository shopRepository, SettingRepository settingRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.shopRepository = shopRepository;
        this.settingRepository = settingRepository;
    }

    public Observable<CheckInResult> checkIn(final Activity context, final String shopId, final String memberId) {

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<CheckInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super CheckInResult> subscriber) {

                final Subscription subscription = new BooleanSubscription();

                shopRepository
                    .checkIn(context, shopId, memberId, settingRepository.getCheckinRssiThreshold())
                    .retryWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<Integer>>() {

                        @Override
                        public Observable<Integer> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> failure) {
                            return failure.flatMap(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<Integer>>() {

                                @Override
                                public Observable<Integer> call(Throwable result) {

                                    if (result instanceof BluetoothFailure) {
                                        return Observable.error(result);
                                    } else if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                                        return Observable.just(0);
                                    } else {
                                        return Observable.error(result);
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMap(new Func1<CheckInResult, Observable<CheckInResult>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<CheckInResult> call(final CheckInResult checkInResult) {
                            return userRepository.checkin()
                                    .map(new Func1<Void, CheckInResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public CheckInResult call(Void aVoid) {
                                            return checkInResult;
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    })
                    .subscribe(subscriber);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean enableCheckin() {
        return userRepository.enableCheckin();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am expecting the `succeeded` array increase by one element, but its size remains empty.

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening, came across asynchronous testing with testschedulers and testsubscribers, but I dont think i am using it right:

in `@Before` I am adding:

```
subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
checkinSubject.subscribe(subscriber);
```

and changed the assertion in `@Test` part to:

```
this.subscriber.assertValueCount(0);
assertEquals(0, succeeded.size());
assertEquals(0, failed.size());

this.checkinSubject.onNext(new CheckInSuccess());

this.subscriber.assertValueCount(1);
assertEquals(1, succeeded.size());
assertEquals(0, failed.size());
```

the `assertValueCount` is working OK but `succeeded` still remains unchanged. How do I get succeeded's assertion to work?

Comment: checkIn() returns an observable btw

Comment: Can you show more code or let it be abstract? Your code it's so specific. It's hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subscribe chain was broken. You should subscribe on the downstream not the upperstream. So subscribe after `doOnError` instead of subscribe dircetly on the `Subject`.

```
this.deviceCheckInUseCase.checkIn()
    .doOnNext(succeeded::add)
    .doOnError(failed::add)
    .subscribe(subscriber);
```

Following is the complete test code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.observers.TestSubscriber;
import rx.subjects.PublishSubject;
import rx.subscriptions.BooleanSubscription;

public class Q47049714 {

  public static class BluetoothFailure extends Exception {
  }

  public static class CheckInSuccess implements CheckInResult {
  }

  public static interface CheckInResult {
  }

  public class ShopRepository {
    public Observable<CheckInResult> checkIn() {
      return checkinSubject;
    }
  }

  public class UserRepository {
    public Observable<Void> checkIn() {
      return Observable.just(null);
    }
  }

  public class DeviceCheckInUseCase {
    ShopRepository shopRepository = new ShopRepository();
    UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

    public Observable<CheckInResult> checkIn() {
      return Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        Subscription subscription = new BooleanSubscription();
        shopRepository
            .checkIn()
            .retryWhen(failure -> failure.flatMap(result -> {
              if (result instanceof BluetoothFailure) {
                return Observable.error(result);
              } else if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
                return Observable.just(0);
              } else {
                return Observable.error(result);
              }
            }))
            .flatMap(checkInResult -> userRepository.checkIn().map(v -> checkInResult))
            .subscribe(subscriber);
      });
    }
  }

  PublishSubject<CheckInResult> checkinSubject;
  DeviceCheckInUseCase deviceCheckInUseCase;
  TestSubscriber<CheckInResult> subscriber;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    checkinSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    deviceCheckInUseCase = new DeviceCheckInUseCase();
  }

  @Test
  public void testCheckInSucceeded() {
    final ArrayList<CheckInResult> succeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    final ArrayList<Throwable> failed = new ArrayList<>();

    deviceCheckInUseCase.checkIn()
        .doOnNext(succeeded::add)
        .doOnError(failed::add)
        .subscribe(subscriber);

    subscriber.assertValueCount(0);
    assertEquals(0, succeeded.size());
    assertEquals(0, failed.size());

    checkinSubject.onNext(new CheckInSuccess());

    subscriber.assertValueCount(1);
    assertEquals(1, succeeded.size());
    assertEquals(0, failed.size());
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input! I removed the subscription on `checkInSubject` and changed it to `checkIn` as you advised, however it brings the same results. I tried setting up breakpoints in `doOnNext` in `checkIn` however it doesnt reach it after executing `this.checkinSubject.onNext(new CheckInSuccess());` .. you asked me to include more code. I am changing my original post to include my entire unit test file. I will also include short/abstract code for `checkIn()`, anything else you would like to be included?

Comment: @JapanGuy Can you also post your updated code (may append after current code)? And I will post my complete code.

Comment: @JapanGuy The code is just mock your environment. It doesn't matter have your method or not. Does this resolve your problem?

Comment: thank you for trying to help! I have edited my question as well

Comment: @JapanGuy It's too long... I will take a look later if you still have problem. But I still think code above is enough to resolve it.

Comment: you changed the code to subscribe after `doOnError()` right? I did that and it is still not working.. Okay!

Comment: @JapanGuy I have updated my code and it works. I don't want to invest effort any more because your code is too long and too board. You should learn how to ask a clearly question first.

Comment: Thank you for your input again! The problem is probably with my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
.observeOn(Schedulers.immediate())
```

before your `doOnNext`. But i'm not sure if it will help.

Comment: First, `Schedulers.immediate()` do nothing, it is for some method contains `Scheduler` argument. And this question is not related to scheduler at all.

Comment: Thought his doOnNext wasn't calling because of this